# Can you set a value in the ScriptProperty of a AppScript Project before pushing via clasp?

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I would like to set a value programmatically in the [ScriptProperty](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) before I push it via [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp#setting) but I could not find a way to do it.

I also could not find any API to set it from outside.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not possible. The Google Apps Script API does not support managing or retrieving information from script properties yet, therefore when using the API you won't be able to see that info.

Because of that when cloning projects using clasp the result is the same, that information will not appear anywhere, hence it can't be managed.

The only available option so far to manage this information is using the setProperties() method from the Properties class from Apps Script itself, but they can't be managed locally before being pushed with clasp in case your end goal was to push changes to the project including all the properties values. The only way is to push the changes to the script and then push the update to the values.

I would still consider this a good idea. I would recommend posting this as a feature request in the Google's issue tracker to see if they can make it possible in the near future.

#### References:

- [setProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setpropertiesproperties)
- [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)

Comment: I just found the `run` functionality in clasp. https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/run.md
what about this? there I could run `setProperties` before I push the actual code

Comment: `Run` would just remotely execute a function online in Apps Script similar to what a trigger does, however that does not execute the function locally to then be able to push it to Apps Script which is what I understand is your end goal.

Comment: The workaround I was mentioning in my post is to run a script using the clasp method for the function to make the changes to the script properties, then clone the script to work it locally, and then push it back to Apps Script.

Comment: but as far as I understand, `run` is not actually pushing the function it is executing. it does not run it locally, but there will be no code regarding setting the properties in my Appscript project right?

Comment: The thing with `run` is that it uses the `scripts.run` method from the Google Apps Script API, and according to the API documentation: `Runs a function in an Apps Script project. The script project must be deployed for use with the Apps Script API and the calling application must share the same Cloud Platform project.` meaning that the script you will use to update the script properties would need to be deployed, and each time you need to modify the script you would need to make a new deployment, so that's pretty much the issue.

Comment: hm ok, well but you have a `setProp(key,value)` function for each AppScript project, and the use `run` before or right after you pushed. But yea that's not the best solution

Comment: That's right. That would be the only possible workaround at the moment. Hopefully Google can add a feature like this soon.